# Facebook API response for groups

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, field

I have added javascript sdk codes from developers.facebook.com

I want to get my user's groups.

```
<script>
   FB.api(
        "/me/groups",
          function (response) {
          if (response && !response.error)
           {
                  /* handle the result */
                  document.getElementById("status").innerText=response;
           }
           });
</script>
```

The only variable that I've got is "response". And when I try to read it, It shows up like [object Object].
I want to get user's group names and check if they are in my group or not.

In Facebook's documentation it says that a group array is returned. I want to get the group array. But have no idea how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` object that you are getting is indeed an Object. You'll need to read a specific property of that object to actually see some content.

You should place a `console.log( response )` in your function callback and then take a look at your JavaScript console to see the contents of the object.

- In **Chrome**, you can open your console by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>
- In **Firefox**, you can open your console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + K</kbd>

The response should look something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "An Awesome Group", 
      "unread": 17, 
      "bookmark_order": 6, 
      "id": "XXXX"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Another Cool Group", 
      "unread": 17, 
      "bookmark_order": 6, 
      "id": "YYY"
    }, 
    ...
   ]
}
```

So what you would need to access is `response.data` - that is where the array is located.

Don't forget to request the [`user_groups` permission from your users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_groups).

Comment: thank you first of all, I used console.log(response) below /*handle the result*/ comment line.
And then I looked up my chrome's console.
There are so many ScriptResource.axd?........ that I couldnt fint which one is mine.

Comment: @MuhammedCAKMAK - then you're not looking at the console. Click the right most tab in the developers tools to view the console's content.

Comment: I've  found the console now, but I couldnt manage it. Can we chat in somewhere else please? I need to show my screenshots to get more help.. or may you simply show how can I simply make a for loop to check each group please? thanks..

Comment: Only users with 20+ reputation can access chat - and you only passed that threshold a few minutes ago so it hasn't updated yet... You can put some screenshots in the comments here until we can open a chat room.

Comment: Ah - well the only thing you should be interested in is that the length of the data array is 0. That means that the user is not a member of any groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62920/discussion-between-lix-and-m1clee).